# NSStatusItem in NSStatusBar, action selector method not responding

Tags: swift, macos, window, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

First I declare the status item:

```
var status_item: NSStatusItem?
```

Then I have a function to close the widow and add the status item:

```
self.view.window?.orderOut(self)
//self.view.window?.close()

self.status_item = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSSquareStatusItemLength)
if let status_button = self.status_item?.button {
    status_button.image = NSImage(named: "StatusBarButtonImage")
    status_button.action = #selector(statusBar(sender:))
}
```

Here's my action selector method, that should remove the status item and show the window again.
Tho it's not being called when pressing the status bar item in the status bar:

```
func statusBar(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("status bar clicked")
    self.status_item = nil
    self.view.window?.orderFront(nil)
}
```

Dose anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Set the button's target to self. I'm assuming you've moved code from the AppDelegate to a separate class. If so, the button is receiving messages from AppDelegate still.

So...

```
if let status_button = self.status_item?.button {
    status_button.image = NSImage(named: "StatusBarButtonImage")
    status_button.action = #selector(statusBar(sender:))
    status_button.target = self //critical line
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the method would be looked up in AppDelegate if the target is not set?